# Correction in regular expression

Tags: regex, string

I have a string that contains a combination of words along with `\r\n` at few places, and `\n` at some places. 
This is a sample:

```
\r\nThis is an\nexample\nand I need\na\nsolution\r\nr\nOK\r\n
```

Now I need to match only `This is an\nexample\nand I need\na\nsolution` along with `\n` in it
This is the expression I tried not working though

```
\r\n([\s\w]+)\r\n
```

This reads the complete string. Correction please

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't want there to be `\r`s within the sentence you match? You could use a negative match:

```
\r\n([^\r]+)\r\n
```

I believe using `\s` will match both `\r` and `\n` as spacing characters

Answer (score 0):

Try using the non-greedy quantifier `?`:

```
\r\n([\s\w]+?)\r\n
```

Comment: That works. I am able to match something like this: `\r\nSucess\r\n\r\nOK\r\n` and this: `\r\nThis is an\nexample\nand I need\na\nsolution\r\nr\nOK\r\n` but not this: `\r\nNews Alerts! Be updated with latest happenings around. Just Dial*777*17# Charges Re.1 per day\r\n\r\nOK\r\n`

Comment: @ Daniel : I got the solution, but would like to know about the `?` quantifier. Can you please explain?

Comment: The non-greedy quantifier basically says: "Select the result that matches the expression and has the minimum amount of characters in it". Example: The string: `aaaa`. The expression `a+?` will match `a`. The expression `a+` will match `aaaa`. `?` matches as little as possible.

Answer (score 0):

A multiline lazy match should work:

```
/\r\n(.+?)\r\n/m
```

Comment: that does not match the string.. Nd why `/` ?

Comment: `/` is a common regex delimiter, e.g. in JavaScript and Ruby and `m` is a multiline modifier. Just use `\r\n(.+?)\r\n` and set the multiline option.